# Declare List<IEntity<T>> where T:class

Tags: c#, list, generic-list

I've made an interface as

```
public interface IEntity<T> where T:class
{
   public Save(T entity);
   public Update(T entity);
   IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
   T GetById(int id);
}
```

Now, I have another class wherein i want to create list of this IEntity type.

```
public class myClass
{
   public List<IEntity<T>> NewList = new List<IEntity<T>>();  // how to tell the compiler where T is class
}
```

but this is giving me error saying

```
The type or namespace name 'T' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will also need to parameterize `myClass`

```
public class myClass<T> where T : class
{
   public List<IEntity<T>> NewList = new List<IEntity<T>>();
}
```

Which you can now instantiate:

```
var instance = new myClass<Foo>();
```

And an obligatory note that it isn't generally good practice to expose member fields as public :)

Note that your interface contains issues:

```
public interface IEntity<T> where T:class
{
   void Save(T entity); // Must have return type
   void Update(T entity); // Drop the public
   IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
   T GetById(int id);
}
```

**Edit, Re Encapsulation**

For example, you could encapsulate with a property with a private setter (list initialized in the constructor) - this will at least stop consumers from re-assigning the list.

```
public IList<IEntity<T>> NewList { get; private set; }

public myClass()
{
    NewList = new List<IEntity<T>>();
}
```

And better still, depending on your design, you could hide the `List` implementation entirely, expose an `IEnumerable<T>` for consumers to read the list, and add explicit methods for changing the internal collection.

Comment: Thnx for the "Notes". I'll try to follow as you said. But how will i be able to declare public List<IEntity<T>> NewList = new List<IEntity<T>>(); in myClass if interface is not public??

Comment: can i have myClass without the parameter T..?
Actually i wanted to create ONE object of myClass & add any T type of to NewList.
In present situation, when initialising myClass<T>, i have to specify T, which i want to avoid